# Expand Seaborn FacetGrid layout horisontally

Tags: seaborn

I have the following code that shows 10 dataframe column values separated by categories PREFERENCE = GOOD and PREFERENCE = BAD.
Is it possible to expand the layout horisontally so that instead of 2 images on one row there are four of them (i.e. ACOUSTIC and DANCE)?

```
for audio_feature in ['ACOUSTIC', 'DANCE', 'DURATION', 'ENERGY', 'INSTRUMENTAL', 'LIVE', 'LOUD', 'SPEECH', 'TEMPO', 'VALENCE']:
    count, bin_edges = np.histogram(features_df[audio_feature])
    g = sns.FacetGrid(features_df, col='PREFERENCE')
    g.map(plt.hist, audio_feature, color="steelblue", bins=bin_edges) #color="coral"
    plt.show()
```

[image]